# Is smoking weed bad for your health?

Tags: medical-science, recreational-drugs, marijuana

Some people believe that smoking marijuana (without any tobacco) is harmful to your health and may cause problems. Examples of things I've heard weed supposedly causes:

- All the health problems of tobacco (cancer, strokes, etc)
- You get addicted to it and can't stop
- It fries your brain
- If you smoke too much you can die

I know for a fact that the last one is false, as the scientific consensus is that an overdose of marijuana in a human being is for all intents and purposes impossible. I'm not sure what "frying your brain" even means, and I don't know about the first two.

Has it been scientifically proven that weed is, or isn't, harmful?

Comment: "I know for a fact" - you shouldn't put your own unreferenced claims in the question (in addition to the claim you are being skeptical about) without references. Also, does anyone have a reasonable link to show the original claim is notable?

Answer (score 104):

It might be that smoking or ingesting marijuana has positive/neutral effects on certain health issues and neutral/negative effects on others. The consensus of studies are generally inconclusive in this regard.

For example, there are studies that say there is a [100% full increase in the odds of suffering from schizophrenia after trying cannabis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15517706?dopt=Abstract)

[Others](http://publichealth.lacounty.gov/ha/present/Staff_researchpapers/YAn_Cui_Articles/Marijuana_Lungca9.pdf) that say:

> 1. "We hypothesized that there would be a positive association between
>      marijuana use and lung cancer, and
>      that the association would be more 
>      positive with heavier use," he said.
>      "What we found instead was no
>      association at all, and even a
>      **suggestion of some protective effect.**"
> 2. "Earlier work established that marijuana does contain cancer-causing
>      chemicals as  potentially harmful as
>      those in tobacco, he said. However,
>      marijuana also contains the  chemical
>      **THC, which he said may kill aging cells and keep them from becoming
>      cancerous**." [- Link to Washington
>      Post Article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2006/05/25/AR2006052501729.html)

and more recently:

[Moderate Marijuana Use Does Not Impair Lung Function, Study Finds](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/11/marijuana-smoking-does-not-harm-lungs-study-finds/?ref=health)

Other studies have been conducted on the specific interaction between THC and cancer cells.  [This study](http://jci.org/articles/view/37948), conducted by the Journal of Clinical Investigation states that:

> ...THC can promote the autophagic
>   death of human and mouse cancer cells
>   and provides evidence that cannabinoid
>   administration **may be an effective
>   therapeutic strategy for targeting
>   human cancers.**

---

Again, I am not overlooking the potential health risks that have been proven to be associated with marijuana use, but I think it is a complex issue and media reports typically focus on potential negative health effects of marijuana use without mentioning potential positive health effects.

I think this graphic helps illustrates my point about the media reports:

[image: Deadliest Drugs]

---

Comment: Very interesting chart. Quite shocking actually how much reports are misleading. But chances of death being close to 0 doesn't mean harm to health is close to 0 too. I still would't advocate smoking weed to protect yourself from cancer, even if cannabinoid administration may be an effective therapeutic strategy for targeting human cancers. :)

Comment: Your answer is amazing. Do you think you could comment on the studies who showed a negative link too? That would make your answer *super amazing*.

Comment: @Borror0 absolutely, when I get a chance I will come back to this question. I have looked at countless studies and oftentimes their focus is marijuana abuse, not marijuana use.  There is an important distinction to be made there, and while the studies themselves may be conducted properly, they should not be used to represent the effects of marijuana use in general.  I think this is mainly a problem with the question that was asked.  Rate/quantity of consumption does not correlate linearly with negative health effects. The question should be more specific on rate of consumption.

Comment: @Egle I wasn't using that graphic to imply what you are saying, just an example of media representation in general.

Comment: @Eratosthenes I was commenting the Post article. I upvoted your answer - it is good.

Comment: I would guess the methadone death-count is slightly exaggerated.  Methadone is used almost exclusively by people trying to break heroin addictions.  A user may be trying to break the addiction exactly because he's in poor health.  Also, the death may have been caused not by the methadone but by a relapse to heroin, or by effects of withdrawal.  Finally, since methadone is typically be prescription, the fact that a given dead person is taking methadone can be easily determined.

Comment: "Again, I am not overlooking the potential health risks that have been proven to be associated with marijuana use." Well you certainly make no mention of them...? Also, there's nothing regarding negative affects on the brain/personality.

Comment: @Malvolio: unlike withdrawl from alcohol or benzodiazapines, it's very rare for someone to die from opiate withdrawls. You're right about death being caused by relapse to heroin, though this applies to other drugs - mixing alcohol and opiates (both are respiratory depressants) is deadly, as is mixing benzos and opiates.

Comment: @rmx -- I was surprised by what you wrote, but my *very* quick skim of the literature seems to back you up: it isn't the fall that kills you or the sudden stop, but getting back up.  Somebody tries to stop using, hates withdrawal, goes and gets as much smack as he can and dies from the overdose.  Anyway, my only point was that methadone will be *known* (since it's prescribed, not bought on the black market) whereas alcohol, benzodiazapine, and heroin have to be *tested* for.  Do they even do autopsies on junkies they find in alleys?

Comment: @Django Reinhardt - some of those studies are posted in other answers in this thread, this is why I didn't bother mentioning them in my answer

Comment: @Eratosthenes, I still think it's worth putting into your answer. For example, the 50% increase in the odds of suffering from schizophrenia after trying cannabis. Links: http://www.nzherald.co.nz/technology/news/article.cfm?c_id=5&objectid=10116853 and http://www.schizophrenia.com/prevention/streetdrugs.html

Comment: @Django Reinhardt I updated my answer

Comment: The only deaths related to pot I've seen have been due to something they have cut the product with (e.g. "love boat"). So I guess, make sure you trust your dealer?

Comment: Tobacco not mentioned?

Comment: @craig why is that relevant?

Comment: @Eratosthenes because I would suggest the death rate of smokers per 10,000 would be vastly higher than any of the drugs mentioned. I have seen some stats suggesting 50% of smokers will die of a related illness.

Comment: Just ran into [a study that found that marijuana *isn't* harmful to lungs!](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/01/11/marijuana-smoking-does-not-harm-lungs-study-finds/?ref=health). Thought I'd add it.

Comment: @Borror0 updated this per your suggestion :)

Comment: How does one calculate the number of deaths reported by the media per 10,000, and come up with a percentage over 100%? Even if the media is making up deaths, how does one determine the ratio of fake deaths to 10,000 users of a substance?

Comment: There is evidence that cannabinoids may slow or reverse brain aging and possibly Alzheimer's disease. There are also studies that indicate marijuana is linked with a drop in IQ in teens. The original poster also asked about addiction. All these should at least be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This answer's unduly positive about the health effects of marijuana, misrepresenting studies about alleged positive health effects and down-playing negative effects.  Also, that infographic at the end has a footnote disclaiming its own numbers as "highly questionable", meaning that not only is it just some blogger's quick estimation, but even the blogger who posted it doesn't stand behind it.  Worse, it's only there to advocate the position that the media unduly picks on marijuana, which doesn't address the question.

Comment: That chart is misleading. First of all, it’s only referring to the UK. Secondly, what are “press reports”? Are they all reports (including “positive” ones) or just “negative” reports? Moreover, even if they are negative, I would bet there are many more press reports about the positive effects of marijuana, or for refuting the negative effects of it, than for the other drugs as well.

Comment: What “media reports” are you talking about? In the U.S, media coverage for arguments and evidence supporting of legalization of marijuana are numerous, to the point where the opposition is represented as backwards and archaic. Legalization of marijuana is a big issue right now with many arguments being reported to favor it. I think this answer is biased in one direction. It's unfortunate this answer has so many upvotes, but it's not surprising.

The idea the press, in general, is biased against marijuana use is anachronistic.

Comment: This answer strikes me as biased.  While weed is relatively quite safe it does have a number of known (generally very minor) health risks.  Mentioning them and putting the low degree of risk into perspective is fine, but not mentioning them at all is not acceptable given the claim being refuted.

Answer (score 36):

1. Weed can cause some health problems, but not greater than tobacco or alcohol. It all depends on quantity/quality and personal health. So for perfectly healthy persons occasional use may have no effect, but for persons with heart problems it can do real damage.
2. Can result in dependence, but less than amphetamines, tobacco or alcohol.
3. No.
4. There are no deaths recorded caused only by using cannabis. But there are deaths associated with usage of weed (car accidents, choking on vomit, etc.)

[Advisory Council on the Misuse of Drugs(UK)](http://www.homeoffice.gov.uk/drugs/acmd/) states that:

> - High use of cannabis is not associated with **major** health
>     problems for individuals or society.
> - Smoking cannabis may be more dangerous than smoking cigarettes
>     because it has a **higher
>     concentration of carcinogens**.
> - Occasional use of cannabis is only rarely associated with significant
>     problems in otherwise healthy
>     individuals, with the main worry being
>     impaired control of your movements. It
>     can also disrupt the control of blood
>     pressure and increase the risk of
>     fainting. However, occasional use can
>     pose **significant dangers** for
>     those with **heart and circulation
>     disorders** and for those with
>     **schizophrenia**.
> - Regular **heavy use** of cannabis **can result in dependence** but
>     its addictive potential is far **less
>     than amphetamines, tobacco or
>     alcohol**.
> - Cannabis impairs mental functions such as attention, memory and
>     performance and so can be dangerous
>     for drivers and those who operate
>     heavy machinery but, unlike alcohol,
>     it does not increase risk-taking
>     behaviour.
> - The birth weight of children whose pregnant mothers smoked joints might
>     be lower than expected due to carbon
>     monoxide in the smoke. They also run a
>     **small risk of minor birth
>     defects**.
> - Cannabis is less harmful than other class B substances including
>     amphetamines, barbiturates or
>     codeine-like compounds.

Comment: Smoking marajuana when underage can affect IQ and brain development in later age.  This is the biggest risk to marajuana in my mind, since the others are so trivial.  I would say it's worth siting: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-pot-really-does-to-the-teen-brain/

Answer (score 18):

There is some evidence that consumption of cannabis can cause shizophrenia in some people ([see this BMJ editorial](http://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.d719.long)), the [newest study about this connection](http://www.bmj.com/content/342/bmj.d738) claims

> Cannabis use is a risk factor for the
>   development of incident psychotic
>   symptoms. Continued cannabis use might
>   increase the risk for psychotic
>   disorder by impacting on the
>   persistence of symptoms.

Comment: Does it mean that it's only a risk factor for people with pre-existing schizophrenia symptoms?

Comment: @smzs No, as far as I interpret it it might cause temporary temporary psychotic experienced to become permanent. The risk seems to be much greater for people with a familiy history of shizophrenia.

Comment: Correlation =/= causation. From your source - "Another possibility is that the association arises because people with psychosis use cannabis to self medicate their symptoms"

Comment: @Syntax Error: The problem with that reverse hypothesis is that it presumes psychosis/schizophrenia is the cause of the cannabis use. [Other studies](http://bmj.bmjjournals.com/cgi/content/abstract/325/7374/1199) have shown that this cannot be the case; psychosis does not precede cannabis use often enough to explain the correlation. However, it is still possible that the two share an (unspecified) cause.

Comment: Depend on Set and Settings, Drug does not produce Schizophrenia itself, but it acts as a neuro-chemical key to free the nervous system from ordinary patterns, if person is not strong enough may develop schizophrenia and even lead to long-term ego/identity loss, but Urban Cannabis is low potency and not really effective hallucinogen.

Comment: More recently, some of the genes variations that predispose to psychosis in healty individuals when smoking cannabis have been identified: https://www.nature.com/mp/journal/v17/n12/full/mp2011187a.html and match at least one of the genes implicated in 1st episode of pshychosis:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22831980 You may want to edit some of these in your answer. For a recent review: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4033190/

Comment: Another, more recent study http://www.nature.com/tp/journal/v6/n2/full/tp2015219a.html

Answer (score 13):

Cannabis is generally pretty innocuous as far as psychoactive drugs go.  It's not *entirely* without negative consequences, however.  There seems to be reasonable evidence (mostly correlative, granted, but there are enough correlations to be worried) for [memory deficits](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20217055) and for [decreased reaction speed in the face of contradictory information](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20721538).

(Linked-to studies picked almost at random from among a number that have similar findings.)

Answer (score 5):

I’m bothered with the ‘you smoke cigarettes and you smoke weed, if cigarettes cause cancer weed does’ anti-science here. There are studies suggest the opposite, that smoking weed can reduce some forms of cancer. I’m not aware of a single study demonstrating that pot smokers who don’t ALSO smoke tobacco have any increased cancer rate.

> [Marijuana use and cancer incidence (California, United States).](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9328194?dopt=Abstract) Sidney
>   S, Quesenberry CP Jr, Friedman GD, Tekawa IS. Source Division of
>   Research, Kaiser Permanente Medical Care Program, Oakland, California
>   94611-5714, USA. Abstract The purpose of this retrospective cohort
>   study was to examine the relationship of marijuana use to cancer
>   incidence. The study population consisted of 64,855 examinees in the
>   Kaiser Permanente multiphasic health checkup in San Francisco and
>   Oakland (California, United States), between 1979-85, aged 15 to 49
>   years, who completed self-administered questionnaires about smoking
>   habits, including marijuana use. Follow-up for cancer incidence was
>   conducted through 1993 (mean length 8.6 years). Compared with
>   nonusers/experimenters (lifetime use of less than seven times), ever-
>   and current use of marijuana were not associated with increased risk
>   of cancer of all sites (relative risk [RR] = 0.9, 95 percent
>   confidence interval [CI] = 0.7-12 for ever-use in men; RR = 1.0, CI =
>   0.8-1.1 in women) in analyses adjusted for sociodemographic factors,
>   cigarette smoking, and alcohol use. Marijuana use also was not
>   associated with tobacco-related cancers or with cancer of the
>   following sites: colorectal, lung, melanoma, prostate, breast, cervix.
>   Among nonsmokers of tobacco cigarettes, ever having used marijuana was
>   associated with increased risk of prostate cancer (RR = 3.1, CI =
>   1.0-9.5) and nearly significantly increased risk of cervical cancer
>   (RR = 1.4, CI = 1.0-2.1). We conclude that, in this relatively young
>   study cohort, marijuana use and cancer were not associated in overall
>   analyses, but that associations in nonsmokers of tobacco cigarettes
>   suggested that marijuana use might affect certain site-specific cancer
>   risks.
>
> [Cannabinoids in the treatment of cancer](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304383509002523)  Amy Alexandera, Paul F.
>   Smitha and Rhonda J. Rosengren , a,   Abstract Cannabinoids, the
>   active components of the hemp plant Cannabis sativa, along with their
>   endogenous counterparts and synthetic derivatives, have elicited
>   anti-cancer effects in many different in vitro and in vivo models of
>   cancer. While the various cannabinoids have been examined in a variety
>   of cancer models, recent studies have focused on the role of
>   cannabinoid receptor agonists (both CB1 and CB2) in the treatment of
>   estrogen receptor-negative breast cancer. This review will summarize
>   the anti-cancer properties of the cannabinoids, discuss their
>   potential mechanisms of action, as well as explore controversies
>   surrounding the results. Keywords: Cannabinoids; JWH-133; CB1; CB2;
>   MAPK
>
> [[The endocannabinoid system as a target for the development of new
>   drugs for cancer therapy].](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12723496) [Article in Italian] Bifulco M, Di Marzo V.
>   Source Dipartimento di Scienze Farmaceutiche, Università di Salerno,
>   Istituto di Endocrinologia ed Oncologia Sperimentale del CNR,
>   Dipartimento di Biologia e Patologia Cellulare e Molecolare,
>   Università Federico II, Napoli. maubiful@unina.it Abstract Studies on
>   the main bioactive components of Cannabis sativa, the cannabinoids,
>   and particularly delta 9-tetrahydrocannabinol (THC), led to the
>   discovery of a new endogenous signalling system that controls several
>   physiological and pathological conditions: the endocannabinoid system.
>   This comprises the cannabinlid receptors, their endogenous
>   agonists--the endocannabinoids--and proteins for endocannabinoid
>   biosynthesis and inactivation. Recently, evidence has accumulated
>   indicating that stimulation of cannabinoid receptors by either THC or
>   the endocannabinoids influence the intracellular events controlling
>   the proliferation and apoptosis of numerous types of cancer cells,
>   thereby leading to anti-tumour effects both in vitro and in vivo. This
>   evidence is reviewed here and suggests that future anti-cancer therapy
>   might be developed from our knowledge of how the endocannabinoid
>   system controls the growth and metastasis of malignant cells. PMID:
>   12723496 [PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE]

Comment: In contrast to tobacco: Association Between Marijuana Exposure and Pulmonary Function Over 20 Years  http://jama.ama-assn.org/content/307/2/173.abstract  "repeated measurements of pulmonary function and smoking over 20 years (March 26, 1985-August 19, 2006) in a cohort of 5115 men and women" "Conclusion Occasional and low cumulative marijuana use was not associated with adverse effects on pulmonary function."

Comment: Cannabis is a well known herbal, I recommend *Food of the gods* by T.McKenna for brief history of psychoactive plants. There are evidence for treatment of Migraine http://www.maps.org/mmj/mjrusso.html, HIV medication http://www.mpp.org/reports/medical-marijuana-hivaids.html and more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_cannabis

Comment: One thing that often gets overlooked when comparing to tobacco, as well, is the fact that one typically takes in a fraction of a joint or maybe a joint per day, vs 20, 30 to 40 cigarettes.

Answer (score 2):

**The National Institute on Drug Abuse (NIDA) admits that cannabis is [not physically addictive](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/research-reports/marijuana/marijuana-addictive), it is [not a gateway to drugs](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/research-reports/marijuana/marijuana-gateway-drug), it does [not cause cancer or emphysema](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/marijuana/what-are-marijuanas-effects-lung-health), there is [no evidence it negatively affects driving](https://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/nti/pdf/812117-Drug_and_Alcohol_Crash_Risk.pdf), there is [no evidence it causes an early onset of psychosis](https://psychcentral.com/news/2013/12/10/harvard-marijuana-doesnt-cause-schizophrenia/63148.html), and there is [no evidence it negatively affects teen IQ](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/twins-study-finds-no-evidence-marijuana-lowers-iq-teens).**

The most important of these is the fact that there is no evidence cannabis negatively affects driving, because the main argument against cannabis legalization is “impaired driving”. It is the only reason anyone could claim to be a victim of cannabis consumption, yet it’s unfounded and doesn’t make anyone a *victim* anyway.

The second most important is that it doesn’t negatively affect teen IQ. This study was done after the popular “marijuana makes kids lose 8 IQ points” nonsense.

---

**Quotes from NIDA:**

In NIDA’s article *Is marijuana a gateway drug?* it says:

> “These findings are consistent with the idea of marijuana as a ‘gateway drug.’ **However the majority of people who use marijuana do not go on to use other, ‘harder’ substances**.”

---

In NIDA’s article *Drugged driving*, they mention this study about cannabis and driving:

https://www.nhtsa.gov/staticfiles/nti/pdf/812117-Drug_and_Alcohol_Crash_Risk.pdf

The study says:

> “The more carefully controlled studies, that actually measured marijuana (THC) use by drivers rather than relying on self-report, and that had more actual control of covariates that could bias the results, **generally show reduced risk estimates or no risk associated with marijuana use** (Elvik, 2013).”

And it concludes:

> “**The results of this study are in line with the previous research on  the effects of marijuana on the risk of crash involvement**. While a number of previous studies have shown some increased risk associated with marijuana use by drivers, **many studies have not found increased risk**. As was noted previously, studies that measure the presence of THC in the drivers' blood or oral fluid, rather than relying on self-report **tend to have much lower (or no elevated) crash risk estimates**.  Likewise,  better controlled studies **have found lower (or no) elevated crash risk estimates**.”

---

In NIDA for Teens’ article *Marijuana*, they mention a major study done on teenage twins. NIDA says:

> “However, two recent twin studies suggest that this decline is related to other risk factors (e.g., genetics, family, and environment), **not by marijuana** use itself.”

The study can be read about here:

http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/twins-study-finds-no-evidence-marijuana-lowers-iq-teens

It says there is no evidence that cannabis consumption with teens causes a lower IQ or any developmental problems.

---

In NIDA’s article *What are marijuana’s effects on lung health?* they say:

> However, while a few small, uncontrolled studies have suggested that heavy, regular marijuana smoking could increase risk for respiratory cancers, **well-designed population studies have failed to find an increased risk of lung cancer associated with marijuana use**.

And:

> Animal and human studies **have not found that marijuana increases risk for emphysema.**

The rest of the article is full of *maybes* without any solid evidence or examples.

---

The DEA factsheet for cannabis still says:

> “**No death from overdose of marijuana has been reported**”

According to the information provided by NIDA, the cannabis vegetable is safer and healthier than the sugar that we sell to children.