# Is marijuana consumption safer than peanut consumption?

Tags: marijuana, recreational-drugs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is smoking weed bad for your health?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/487/is-smoking-weed-bad-for-your-health)

According to this image I found on Facebook, the claim is made that "Marijuana is safer than peanuts."  Presumably this is referring strictly to the consumption (and not trafficking-related) deaths of these substances.

Never mind the incredibly fuzzy facts, and likely overlapping categories of the other death statistics (I suspect tobacco-related deaths and poor diet/exercise related deaths are often related to each other, for instance).  Lets only focus on peanut-related deaths versus marijuana-related deaths.

I'm also assuming that this image refers to U.S. deaths, but I'm interested in any relevant answer, citing U.S. statistics, or world-wide statistics.

So the two specific, but related questions I have are:

1. Are there zero marijuana-related deaths per year?
2. If not, are there fewer marijuana-related deaths than peanut-related deaths each year?

[Annual Deaths by various drugs/substances http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/310872_254644027915337_100001092265103_745036_1205832753_n.jpg](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/310872_254644027915337_100001092265103_745036_1205832753_n.jpg)

Comment: Consumption can be by cookies, chocolate and tea. The other question is about smoking. And: How do you die from peanuts? (Smoking?)

Comment: Presumably the peanut deaths are related to consumption by those with severe peanut allergies.

Comment: So for those, who know, that they don't suffer from such allergies, it is a misguiding comparison.

Comment: Some people are so deathly allergic that even being in the same room as peanuts can be dangerous... In such (rare) cases, even knowing isn't always sufficient to prevent an allergic attack. (The recent movie "Horrible Bosses" makes light of this condition in the character played by Kevin Spacey)

Comment: I didn't knew that, but thought of unknown ingredients, so that's the reason why I only wrote about people, who are aware, that they are **not** allergic.