# Is cannabis bad for your health, when not smoked, in the long term?

Tags: medical-science, recreational-drugs, marijuana

This question is not about *smoking* cannabis. The scope of this question is limited to other methods of consumption such as edibles, tinctures, and transdermal patches.

The Wikipedia article on [the long-term effects of cannabis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_effects_of_cannabis) says that studies show that cannabis usage by teenagers may cause permanent cognitive impairment, but except at very high doses, this has not been established for adults.

It says that it may raise the risk of schizophrenia in susceptible individuals.

It also says that cannabis usage during pregnancy may cause permanent damage to an unborn child.

Also, preliminary research suggests that cannabis consumption may prevent Alzheimer's disease.

There is a similar question asked on this site: [Is smoking weed bad for your health?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/487/is-smoking-weed-bad-for-your-health), but this other question deals primarily with the negative effects of *smoking*.

My question is, what do we know today about the long-term effects of cannabis consumption besides smoking?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it on-topic for the site and not a duplicate of the other weed question.

Comment: I see that my question has been retitled "Is cannabis bad for your health when not smoked?"  I don't like this new title as my original title was about the "long term effects" of cannabis usage.  I specifically wanted to learn about what it does in the long run, positive or negative.  The new title suggests that I'm simply asking for a list of dangers.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2010, there was "insufficient evidence, particularly because of the low number of studies, to assess whether the all-cause mortality rate is elevated among cannabis users in the general population. Case–control studies suggest that some adverse health outcomes may be elevated among heavy cannabis users, namely, fatal motor vehicle accidents, and possibly respiratory and brain cancers." (Calabria *et al.* 2010)

#### References

Calabria, Bianca, Louisa Degenhardt, Wayne Hall, and Michael Lynskey. "Does cannabis use increase the risk of death? Systematic review of epidemiological evidence on adverse effects of cannabis use." Drug and Alcohol Review 29, no. 3 (2010): 318-330.

Comment: Just started the answer off with a possibly out-of-date systematic review. It's community wiki, so feel free to update with newer or complementary evidence.