# Does smoking marijuana cause acne?

Tags: marijuana, dermatology, acne

My teenage son has started smoking weed and I'm not happy about it, since I'm not a believer in "forbidding" thing over "convincing" I have tried to bring the topic to medical level, and he's had a convincing counter-argument every time, but since he started his acne has gone bad so it was easy to blame it on weed, but I cannot find any conclusive answer.

[Medical News Today's answer](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/does-smoking-weed-cause-acne) is very confusing:

> It is unlikely that smoking weed causes acne. However, some people who already have acne might find that it worsens or improves if they smoke marijuana

It lists potential side effects:

> possible link between smoking weed and a rise in testosterone levels

No-one mentions acne in this question [Is smoking weed bad for your health?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/487/is-smoking-weed-bad-for-your-health)

This [skin treatment site](https://www.exposedskincare.com/blogs/blog/can-smoking-weed-cause-acne) claims:

> While not definitive, several indirect links exist between marijuana use and acne

and even goes to say:

> Some compounds found in marijuana, known as cannabinoids, have been shown to have anti-inflammatory properties. This discovery led some to claim that smoking weed could even help treat acne.

This claim of CBD helping acne is backed up by [Health News](https://healthnews.com/nutrition/vitamins-and-supplements/best-cbd-oil-for-inflammation/):

> Topical CBD may help acne by decreasing inflammation, the proliferation of skin cells, and sebum (oil) production, all of which contribute to acne formation

Another [skin treatment site](https://skywardtreatment.com/blog/acne-when-you-smoke-weed/) states:

> Marijuana indirectly causes acne because weeds can make you unbelievably hungry and can change your hormones.

A [medical study](https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/25/7/1567) part of [Research on the Cannabinoid Receptors Pharmacology](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/molecules/special_issues/cannabinoid_receptorspharm) explores:

> the effect of terpenoids, cannabimimetic ligands, beyond the Cannabis plant in different pathological conditions, such as Herpes infection, diabetic retinopathy, psoriasis, asthma, AD, seizures, ischemic stroke, and others

[Terpenoids, Cannabimimetic Ligands, beyond the Cannabis Plant](https://www.mdpi.com/molecules/molecules-25-01567/article_deploy/html/images/molecules-25-01567-g003.png)

Since I cannot find conclusive studies I tried to rely on first hand experiences and read many other blogs on the subject, and it's always "yes and no". Here are a few:

- [Does Smoking Weed Cause Acne? Yes & No](https://launchcenters.com/does-smoking-weed-cause-acne/)
- [Does Smoking Weed Really Cause Acne?](https://www.nuggmd.com/blog/weed-and-acne)
- [Marijuana Might Be Affecting Your Skin... And Not In The Ways You Thought](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/marijuana-and-skin_n_4214041)
- [Does Smoking Weed Cause Acne? Unveiling the Truth](https://givingtreedc.com/does-smoking-weed-cause-acne-unveiling-the-truth/)

Does smoking weed cause acne?

Comment: This question was falsely flagged as spam by automatic bots, and confirmed by a human, but then someone flagged it (thank you!) and it was rescued. Sorry for the bad first experience, Sajmir.

Comment: By-the-by you can and should not allow him to smoke in your house. It is your house and you don't have to allow anything that goes against your values.